# WeakReferences in a HashMap

Tags: java, generics, weak-references

I want to store a HashMap of Callbacks. These callbacks are generics. For some reasons the garbage collector can and should remove those instances. The keys of this map should be the type of the callback.

```
interface Callback<T> {
    void callbackMethod(T result)
}

void someMethod(Callback<String> cb) {
    myMap.put(String.class, cb);
    ...
}

<T> void someOtherMethod(T result) {
    myMap.get(T.class).callbackMethod(result);
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure this compiles, maybe `result.getClass()` instead of `T.class`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weak hashmap with weak references to the values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889051/weak-hashmap-with-weak-references-to-the-values)